# What's the reason my T extends undefined condition does not work in the context of a property?

Tags: typescript

Here is the code:

```
export const quickPrompt = async <T>({
  name,
  prompt,
  zodSchema,
  onUpdate,
}: {
  name: string;
  onUpdate: () => Promise<{ cancelled: boolean }>;
  prompt: string;
  zodSchema?: z.ZodType<T>;
}): Promise<T extends undefined ? string : T> => {
```

and here how it is invoked:

```
const content = await quickPrompt({
  name: 'writeArticleSection',
  onUpdate,
  prompt,
});
```

or

```
const content = await quickPrompt({
  name: 'writeArticleSection',
  onUpdate,
  prompt,
  zodSchema: z.array(z.string())
});
```

In the first case, I expect that `content` would have type `string` (because `T extends` undefined`) and in the second I expect it to be` string[]`(because`T`does not extend`undefined`)

I've tried using `T extends never` and such, but I cannot get it to work as expected.

Comment: If the question isn't *about* zod then can you [edit] the code so it doesn't depend on it?  Or else tag the question with zod so that relevant experts can notice it?  Ideally the code should be a standalone [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  Also be sure to explicitly say what the problem is; as far as I can see you're saying it doesn't work, but that's not enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the first case, I expect that content would have type string (because T extends undefined)

That's not correct.

Unconstrained generics are implicitly constrained by `unknown`, not `undefined`. If you hover over the invocation of `quickPrompt` invocation without the schema, it should show the type of the generic parameter as:

```
const quickPrompt: <unknown>({ name, ...
//                  ^ here
```

Instead you can give the *default* type for `T` as `undefined` and now that type will be used if nothing can be inferred.

```
const quickPrompt: <T = undefined>({ ... }) => { /*...*/ }
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgFBnECmAxgDYCGUVcNEAdgM7wCOArsBoBrAAo5wMAFxwAPABU4AXjh921TMHZViAPgAUCMnDjsGIKgBojcMOLAwrxosQDKNABZUQDR3A4BVMGIGGEsyNGlDY1NzaW4oTQBzAG5rAKCQqmk9AEolHTgxXGBOKhkkGgZ2Gio6Om1pACMICHqq9B1U41tceziYBPYU62c3T28AfmlkADoALRI5AE8wMrlO8LzFAqKQErW4KgAPULVOFTUqDS1iOAm4eKS4aXWKNi54d9OYAEYlOAYAHcGMBeAJhLt7AZrAB6GFwAB6E2sMSyBEBCVCAEFYIJ6i5aDBgBx8L50sFQtIGJwltU4Ll8vSKlUanUGlgGHRSugcr4ehJpPhQtxSZtUmR3txWBxvgAmf5AkFgwSiOwwaHGOGI5HRMxo-AY0FUHFE+hUAk0IkksnsQIUtHU2k0elbAoGVgs2r1YjSTCc7loXnWfl9AjCmCipwkMZeBjTGZMKAMJZ6WaPIa5HJioA)

---

Usually though, assigning to a conditional type is going to be hard to pull off. Function overloads would probably serve you better:

```
// No schema
function quickPrompt(options: {
  name: string;
  onUpdate: () => Promise<{ cancelled: boolean }>;
  prompt: string;
  zodSchema?: undefined;
}): Promise<string>

// with schema
function quickPrompt<T>(options: {
  name: string;
  onUpdate: () => Promise<{ cancelled: boolean }>;
  prompt: string;
  zodSchema: z.ZodType<T>;
}): Promise<T>

// implementation
function quickPrompt(options: {
  name: string;
  onUpdate: () => Promise<{ cancelled: boolean }>;
  prompt: string;
  zodSchema?: z.ZodType<unknown>;
}): Promise<unknown> {
  return {} as any // TODO: implement
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JU0VioreEswXHi4XQ3nb+XWunwHnMbcj3nsZHj5meYg8JIATKmuOnMytaeshw5RsXSycCJXJuxayJmA2m1TVxcBC5uZ4e32+SCIdnhHMV3iwSdp06Oc4AVQEl3YFcYIqCFag1GEuCgKAuCRFRNXZGwfG8NdbCAA)

Comment: Thank you. I've learned something new!